# yasnippets always puts new snippets in c-mode instead of php-mode -- how do I change this?

Tags: emacs, code-snippets

The yasnippets module for emacs allows the dynamic expansion of words as snippets much like abbrev mode, but more powerful, and is similar to the snippet system used in TextMate on OS X.

I'm hoping there is another php author out there using this module. When I try to create a new snippet in php-mode, it instead puts it in c-mode, as php-mode.el says it is a derived mode of c-mode. yasnippet isn't acting incorrectly, exactly, as there really is no php-mode defined here, just c-mode. However, I'd really like it if I could still have new snippets made under php-mode.

What's kind of odd is that yasnippets will read and process snippets under php-mode directories in my snippets directory. However, it also shows whatever c-mode snippets might be defined as well.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a file named `.yas-parents` under the php-mode snippets dir and put `text-mode` in it. That should sever the connection with cc-mode (if that's really what you wish). I guess that some c snippets might be useful in php-mode as well.